# How do I block a subdirectory from WordPress theming?

Tags: themes, htaccess, directory, css

I have a WordPress site. It works great. But I have a subdirectory on my server where I work on client websites. It's a development space and most of those sites are NOT WordPress. Sometimes (but not all the time?) my site's WordPress theme will takeover a page and mess up all my styles.

I don't care so much about WHY this is happening... but how do I prevent it? I assume I need to edit my .htaccess with some extra line of code.

Alright, here's a page that's being corrupted by WP styles:

- See my current WP site at fowlertown.com
- Here's a non-WP page on a new site I'm building: http://fowlertown.com/projects/fowler6/case-studies/dancefx.html
- Here's how that page SHOULD look: http://fowlertown.com/projects/fowler6/industry-experience/higher-education.html

Notice the header and footer; the middle section is broken right now anyway.

Comment: You should care about why is happening because if you dont know why is happening you won't can prevent it. Can you clarify exactly what happens? Wordpress takes styles CSS files from the subdirectoy you want to block? Wordpress execute the URL request to the subdirectory as own?

Comment: please be more specific. Add some url examples what subdirectory you want to allow and what not.

Comment: I've edited my OP with a couple examples. Noticeable in header and footer the most, my WP theme is overwriting some CSS styles I have in a non-WP subdirectory.

Comment: you have the contents of your theme's header.php being injected into the middle of your html page, I presume this is the result of something you're doing in the code on that particular page.

Comment: Yeah... I should've noticed that. It's from a broken SSI. As a result, server returns a 404 which WordPress tries to intercept. Thanks for the observation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out my trouble was caused by a stray server-side include that was returning a 404, which WordPress tried to intercept.

`This is not the WordPress problem you are looking for.`